# How to add .html suffix in wagtail?

Tags: django, wagtail

The wagtail url only accept slug type, no `.` acceptable.

Can I add suffix like `.html` at end of url, like `/faq.html` instead of `/faq/`?

Comment: Why do you want the .html extension? It provides no benefit to the end user, and recommended practice is to leave it out if your software permits it (for example, see "What to leave out" at https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI).

Comment: @gasman It's legacy issue we have to keep some old urls without any redirect for seo. Anyway, I already solved this one by overriding bunch of stuff

Comment: @TianchengLiu can you answer how you solved this issue so that people with same requirements can benefits?